# Can't post an answer although very low activity?

Tags: support, answers, post-ban

I'm trying to help out a fellow Git user on SE ([Deploy a GIT project on OVH "Mutualisé" (shared)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33822876/deploy-a-git-project-on-ovh-mutualis%C3%A9-shared)) but I can't post an answer because I'm apparently banned.

From what I see, I only posted one question on SE about Ruby, got my answer and validated it right. I don't see why couldn't I post answers.

Could you help me please? This is very frustrating because I won't post dump questions/answers.

Here's the answer I'd like to post:

> Hi Zl3n,
>
> I just tried my [own tutorial][1] (which you asked for help onto) to
>   if it works and it still does. I believe there's an issue in the way
>   you understand the tutorial or in your Windows Git configuration.
>
> **Here's what I did step by step:**
>
> Supposing you have a `git` folder in your OVH's server home dir. On my
>   local machine:
>
> ```
> $ mkdir test.git
> $ cd test.git
> $ git init --bare
> $ cd ..
> $ scp -r test.git {user}@ssh.cluster{XXX}.ovh.net:git
> $ rm -rf test.git
> ```
>
> If you already having issues here, there's definitely something wrong
>   with your Git config. Then, let's use the newly created repo:
>
> ```
> $ git clone {user}@ssh.cluster{XXX}.ovh.net:git/test.git
> ```
>
> That's it.
>
> I don't have any specific Git configuration that says whether to use
>   HTTPS over SSH or such.
>
> Keep in mind that, as far as I remember, the OVH server hasn't access
>   to the outside world unless by FTP and SSH. You might want to verify
>   this tho.
>
> [1]:
>   http://blog.eexit.net/git-creer-des-depots-prives-sur-du-mutualise/

Comment: What exactly you see when submitting? What is the error message?

Comment: You had posted a number of "answers" back in 2012, which were deleted shortly after being posted (these were either "me too" or follow on questions - not actual answers). These would be why your account is in an answer ban.

Comment: Given how long ago these were and that this does appear to be a legitimate answer, I have given you a bit of a push out of the answer ban. Go forth and give proper answers :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard

The error I have is: `We are no longer accepting answers from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.`

Comment: @Oded Aaah, this sucks! Looks like my start on SE was very bad! :(
So, what's the process now?

Comment: @Joris you can post answers now, Oded removed your ban. (probably by disassociating the old deleted answers from your account)

Comment: @ShadowWizard & Oded thank you so much!

Comment: All @Oded doing, I just explained. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Alright, I believe the fact that I posted this question and interacted with the comments made my reputation grow a little bit then I have been able to submit my answer.

Or maybe @Oded (from the comments) did some magic here.

Comment: Be sure to take the Tour on any site you use. It is a 2 minute intro to the Help which starts to guide you away from all the "Me too", "Hi", "Thanks", etc inclusions that are not just unnecessary but discouraged in our wikified Q&A.